# Cannot access some websites over PPTP (VPN)

Tags: ip, vpn, vps, pptp, l2tp

I cannot load some websites over PPTP but I can load these websites over L2TP.

For example, I cannot load http://speedtest.net over PPTP...

The MRU and MTU are the same for these two protocols : 1400.

The VPN servers are installed on my VPS.

Anyone experiencing the same issue ?
Is it related to the server or to the client ?

Thank you.